# How to show user input data in json format using thymeleaf and SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

> I create a dynamic user registration form  and I want to show the User
> input data as json format  in Sequence fill by user. But I am Not able
> to get this type of data. I want to send and get data in Below format.

```
{
 "advertise_id": 16,
 "form": [
   {
     "type": "text",
     "subtype": "email",
     "required": false,
     "label": "Email",
     "className": "form-control",
     "name": "email",
     "access": false,
     "value": "alex.pandiyan@gmail.com"
   },
   {
     "type": "date",
     "required": true,
     "label": "Date of Birth",
     "className": "form-control",
     "name": "dob",
     "access": false,
     "value": "2002-07-21",
     "description": "dob"
   }
 ]
}
```

> I want to send values  when user click on signup button
> Signup.html

```
<div class="singup-form">
<form method="post" th:action="@{/signup}">
<input id="id" th:field="*{id}" type="hidden"/>
<input id="form" name="form" th:field="*{form}" type="hidden"/>
<div th:each="item,iterStat : *{form}">
<div class="form-group">
<label th:for="${item.name}" th:text="${item.label}"></label>
<div th:if="${item.validation == 'dob'}">
<input class="form-control" th:id="${item.name}" th:name="${item.name}"
th:placeholder="${item.placeholder}" th:required="${item.required}"
th:type="${item.type}" th:attr="max=${#dates.format(item.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"/>
</div>
<div th:unless="${item.validation == 'dob'}">
<input class="form-control" th:id="${item.name}" th:name="${item.name}"
th:placeholder="${item.placeholder}" th:required="${item.required}"
th:type="${item.type}"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

> SignUp.kt

```
package com.ape.model

data class SignUp(
    val id: Int,
    val email: String? = "",
    val login_type: String? = "",
    val dob: String? = ""
)

data class ModelSignUp(
    val firstname: String? = "",
    val month: String? = "",
    val day: String? = "",
    val year: String? = "",
    val email: String? = "",
    val phone_number: String? = "",
)
```

> Advertisement.kt

```
package com.ape.model

import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class Advertisement(
    val form:ArrayList<Form>?=null,
)

class ErrorResponse(
    var message: String? = ""
)
class Form(
    val type:String="",
    val required:Boolean,
    val label:String="",
    val placeholder:String="",
    val name:String="",
    val value:String="",
    val validation:String="",
    val min:Int,
    var date: Date = Date(),
)
```

> Homecontroller.kt

```
@PostMapping("/signup")
    fun submitSignUpDetails(@RequestParam(name = "form") form: ArrayList<Form>): String {
        val arrayList = arrayListOf<Map<String, Any>>()
        form.forEach {
            val map = hashMapOf<String, Any>()

            arrayList.add(map)
        }
        print("Lisst $arrayList")

        return "signup"
    }
```

> How to send data as json format. I use thymeleaf as font end and
> Spring boot as back end.

Comment: Why do you want to send data as JSON? Thymeleaf does not work that way. You might want to read up on [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf).

Answer (score 2):

> You can use map inside and arrayList because json show's data in key
> value pair, so you can follow these Lines
> fun getSubmitDetail(jsonMap: Map<String, Any>,model: Model): Boolean {
> var isError = false

```
    val arrayList = ArrayList<Map<String, Any?>>()
    advertisement?.form?.forEach {
        val map = hashMapOf<String, Any?>()
        map["type"] = it.type
        map["required"] = it.required.toString()
        map["label"] = it.label
        map["placeholder"] = it.placeholder
        map["name"] = it.name
        map["value"] = jsonMap[it.name].toString()
        map["validation"] = it.validation
        map["min"] = it.min.toString()

        arrayList.add(map)
    }
```